# create function mysql error

Tags: mysql

Here is my function

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE FUNCTION specialUser(user INT) RETURNS user_id INT
BEGIN
    DECLARE user_id INT DEFAULT 0;
    CASE 
     WHEN user = 1556 THEN SET user_id = 1001;
     WHEN user = 1018 THEN SET user_id = 1002;
     WHEN user = 3658 THEN SET user_id = 1003;
         ELSE SET user_id = user;
    END CASE;
 RETURN user_id;
END//
```

I get error:

You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'user_id INT
    BEGIN
        DECLARE user_id INT DEFAULT 0;
        CASE 
        ' at line 1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can only state the *type* of the result, there's no use in giving an *identifier*, so:

```
CREATE FUNCTION specialUser(user INT) RETURNS INT
```

instead of

```
CREATE FUNCTION specialUser(user INT) RETURNS user_id INT
```